# How to use Python to write to a CSV File?

Tags: python, csv, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to use Python and Tweepy to scrape a list of followers from a specific user.  I can get the program to print the list of users but I am having trouble getting it to write to a CSV file.  How would I make it so that it writes to a CSV file? Also, how would I make it so that there are no commas in between individual users screen names in the CSV file?

```
import tweepy
import csv

consumer_key = "XXX"
consumer_secret = "XXX"
access_token = "XXX"
access_token_secret = "XXX"

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
  consumer_key, consumer_secret,
   access_token, access_token_secret
)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

csvFile = open('followers.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for follower in api.get_followers(screen_name='twitteruser'):

  print(follower.screen_name)
  
  csvWriter.writerow(follower.screen_name)
csvFile.close()
```

Comment: If you don't have fields, then you don't need a CSV file.  You just need a file.  Use `print(follower.screen_name, file=csvFile)`.

Comment: The REASON yours doesn't work is that `writerow` expects to be given a list of things.  When you give it a string, it writes each letter as a different field.

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to show what your expected output format would look like

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already working with external dependencies (such as Tweepy) I suggest you working with Pandas! It's the best package to handle CSVs - however you don't want to use it everywhere to do every simple task because it's very heavy, but I don't think it will matter in you case.

- [How to read a CSV with Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).
- [How to write a CSV with Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

You can also read and write the CSV with other delimiters, such as tabs or whatever character you want, using the argument `sep` in the `pd.to_csv` method, solving your comma demand.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I'd recommend opening your file for writing:

csvFile = open('followers.csv', 'w')

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the `csv` package here, as your use-case is pretty simple. Also, I'd highly recommend using a [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) instead of manually opening and closing files.

Here's a way of doing what you want:

```py
with open('followers.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
    for follower in api.get_followers(screen_name='twitteruser'):
        csvFile.write(f"{follower.screen_name}\n")
```